# Error after installing mysqlnd_ms

Tags: amazon-ec2, php5, php.ini, amazon-ami, php

I am working on Amazon EC2 using the Amazon Linux AMI which is based on CentOS. I have installed php54 and php54-mysqlnd.

Then I do a `sudo pecl install myslqnd_ms`. This installs fine. I add the extension into the php.ini file. Then I start httpd, and when I do in the error log I see:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_ms.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/mysqlnd_ms.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_globals in Unknown on line 0
```

Googling this lead me to this thread on [bugs.php.net](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62276&edit=1) and [other forum](http://forums.famillecollet.com/viewtopic.php?id=242). Neither of which helped me much.

What would be the best solution here? I am trying to stick to stock pre built binaries from the main YUM repo if possible.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this issue:

Remove the lines like:

```
mysqlnd_ms.enable=1
mysqlnd_ms.force_config_usage=1
mysqlnd_ms.config_file=/etc/mysqlnd_ms_cfg.ini
extension=mysqlnd_ms.so
```

from the `php.ini` file

Create a new file called `/etc/php.d/mysqlnd_ms.ini` and put those lines in there and restart php-fpm

```
service php-fpm restart
```